# DOM event / DOM selector

Tags: events, dom, mouseevent

I have a wordpress page where I want to create custom events. 
I would like to measure how many people click on different links/entries on my page.

I have been reading and I should create in HTML an on click DOM event for those entries/links, but I am not sure how to set this up. 
Then I also require the DOM selector.

Would somebody give me an example of how to do this? 
Below is an example of how it looks an entry on HTML:

**-Shoes: [Click acá!](https://www.paruolo.com.ar/)**

Thanks very much.
Sabrina C.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're asking for:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

A better solution might be:

```
<a onclick="log(this)" href="https://www.paruolo.com.ar/" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Click acá!</a>

<script>
function log(e){
    alert(e.href);
    alert(e.innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

This would allow you to pass the item to a fetch call that you replace the alert with to log on your server or on the page. Just replace the alert with another function that handles your data and handle by link or the text in the link.